# how to limit tests time execution from build xml file

Tags: java, junit, ant

basically, in case a  test takes more than 2 minutes abort that particular test and continue with others, I have this piece

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" haltonerror="no">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${build.test}"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path" />
      </classpath>
      <formatter type="plain" usefile="no"/>
      <batchtest fork="yes"  haltonfailure="no" haltonerror="no" failureproperty="test.failed" todir="../src/result">
        <fileset dir="${build.test}">
          <include name="**/app/**/*Test.*"/>
          <exclude name="**/app/**/*Helper*"/>
</fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [junit ant doc](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), you have `timeout` attribute :

> timeout - Cancel the individual tests if they don't finish in the given time
>   (measured in milliseconds). Ignored if fork is disabled. When running
>   multiple tests inside the same Java VM (see forkMode), timeout applies
>   to the time that all tests use together, not to an individual test.

```
<junit fork="yes" timeout="60000" >
```

If `forkmode` is set to `perTest` by default, timeout value is for each individual test, but if you specify `forkmode` to `once`, a single JVM will run all the tests and the value applies for all your tests.